# Multiple aynchronous network calls blocking main thread because their output at same time?

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, priority-queue, rx-android

I am using priority job queue , there are number of jobs running in parallel, so that their result populates on UI at same time which takes application to ANR, is there any way , so that i can run asynchronous calls and populate ui synchronously?

Comment: can you post what exactly are you doing with code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip` operator of `rxjava2` to merge the responses together and when the combined response comes you can **populate the UI synchronously** .. for reference you can check..

http://www.codexpedia.com/android/rxjava-2-zip-operator-example-in-android/

> **Note** The zipper will the return merged response after all the responses are received

Comment: user will wait for other calls to finish , as there can be any number of calls . I want to populate data one by one so user will get something first and one by one  all the data . Can you help with this?

Comment: after the response comes it will be populate the view one by one in the main thread... or you can also slow down the process by using **handlers**

Answer (score 0):

UI is always populated synchronously, if it is done in correct way. The correct way is to call `activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)`, directly or indirectly. Seems that your problem is that your jobs post to UI thread in a too high rate.

First, check if the `Runnable`s to update UI does only UI work. Any calculations should be done outside the UI thread. If it is so, create an intermediate object which makes pauses between UI updates from the parallel jobs and so lets the UI thread to respond to updates from user. It can look as follows:

```
public class PauseMaker {
  Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);
  public void runOnUiThread(Runnable r) {
    sem.aquire(); 
    Thread.sleep(1);
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
      try {
        r();
      } finally {
        sem.release();
      }
    });
  } 
}
```